# Convert a natural number to binary using recursion

Tags: recursion

I have to convert a natural number to binary but using recursion. I did but without recursion:

```
int main (){
  int n,pot,bin;

  printf("Digite o Numero:\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  pot=1;
  bin=0;
  while (n>0){
    bin+=(n%2)*pot;
    pot*=10;
    n= n/2;
  }

  printf ("%d",bin);
  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that this is the first time this question has ever been asked!

Answer (score 0):

something like (ASSUMING n is positive!):

```
void getBin(uint n, int pot, int* bin) {
    *bin += (n%2)*pot;
    n /= 2;
    if (n <= 0) {
       return;
    }
    getBin(n, pot * 10, bin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side this does not convert a positive number to binary. It creates a number that, when displayed in base 10, looks like the argument in base 2. 
A better solution would be to convert the number to char* in a given base.

```c
int getBin(int n) {
  return getBinHelper(n, 1, 0);
}

int getBinHelper(int n, int e, int acc) {
  return n == 0 ?
         acc : 
         getBinHelper( n/2, e*10, n&1 ? acc+e : acc);
}
```